# Grails V2.3.7 starts up application automatically during test-app functional:

Tags: grails

I recently upgraded Grails to V2.3.7 and noticed that when I ran `grails test-app functional:` the application would be started up automatically like so:

```
:grails-test-app-functional
| Loading Grails 2.3.7
| Configuring classpath
| Running pre-compiled script
| Running pre-compiled script.
| Environment set to test
| Environment set to test.
| Environment set to test..
| Environment set to test...
| Environment set to test....
| Environment set to test.....
| Compiling 1 source files
| Compiling 1 source files.
| Compiling 1 source files..
| Compiling 1 source files...
| Compiling 1 source files....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Running Grails application
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/myApplication
```

This did not happen in V2.3.6. My questions are:
1) Is this new in V2.3.7 or did I configure something unknowingly?
2) How do I disable this auto running of the app?

Thanks.

Comment: Jeff has the answer. One enhancement you can do here is make functional tests run against a port other than 8080. Doing so it wont clash with another app running in 8080, if you are working on multiple grails app simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

The app has to be started in order to run your functional tests.  The functional tests interact with the running app.  This has always been the case.

Comment: Thanks. But I always had to manually start up my app prior to upgrading to 2.3.7. Any idea why that was happening?